# In Rails, what is the inverse of update_attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In Rails, what is the inverse of `update_attributes!` ?

In other words, what maps a record to an attributes hash that would recreate that record and all of it children records?

The answer is not `ActiveRecord.attributes` as that will not recurse into child object.

To clarify if you have the following:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars
end
```

Then you can pass an hash like

`{"name" => "a foo", "bars_attributes" => [{"name" => "a bar} ...]}`

to `update_attributes`. But it's not clear how to easily generate such a hash programatically for this purpose.

EDIT:
As I have mentioned in a comment, I can do something like:
`foo.as_json(:include => :bars)`

but I wanted a solution that uses the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars` declaration to avoid having to explicitly include associations.

Comment: What do you mean by "would recreate that record and all of it children records"?

Comment: Generating the hash is fairly easy, use the same methodology you use for responding to JSON with relations, then parse it into a hash. (Not saying that's the most *efficient* method, though.)

Comment: try `obj.association_cache` that would give you a whole lot more as an hash

Comment: @DaveNewton, I can use `as_json` or `to_json` as needed, but then I have to pass in a hash such as `{:include => {:bars => {:include => :bazs}}} ...`. I was hoping to avoid that as the model already knows what it `accept_nested_attributes` for.

Comment: @z5h Yeah, that's true. There's probably a nested hash AR/object dumper, though, there must be.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how that would be the "inverse", but while Rails might not "have the answer" per-see, there is nothing stopping you from traversing through an object and creating this VERY efficiently.

Something to get you started:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for

You'll notice in the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method, rails sets a hash for all models nested, in `nested_attributes_options`. So we can use that to get these nested associations, to populate this new hash.

```
def to_nested_hash
  nested_hash = self.attributes.delete_if {|key, value| [:id, :created_at, :deleted_at].include? key.to_sym } # And any other attributes you don't want

  associations = self.nested_attributes_options.keys
  associations.each do |association|
    key = "#{association}_attributes"
    nested_hash[key] = []
    self.send(association).find_each do |child|
      nested_hash[key] << child.attributes.delete_if {|key, value| [:id, :created_at, :deleted_at].include? key.to_sym }
    end
  end

  return nested_hash
end
```

### OR just thought of this:

Using your example above:

```
foo.as_json(:include => foo.nested_attributes_options.keys)
```

One thing to note, this won't give you the `bars_attributes` where my first suggestions will. (neither will `serializable_hash`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to include nested options in hash

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars

  def to_nested_hash(options = nil)
    options ||= {}
    if options[:except]
      incl = self.nested_attributes_options.keys.map(&:to_s) - Array(options[:except]).map(&:to_s)
    else
      incl = self.nested_attributes_options.keys
    end
    options = { :include => incl }.merge(options)
    self.serializable_hash(options)
  end
end
```

If for some situations you don't want bars, you can pass options

```
foo.to_nested_hash(:except => :bars)
```

**Edit:** Another option if you want same behaviour in `as_json`, `to_json` and `to_xml`

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars

  def serializable_hash(options = nil)
    options ||= {}
    if options[:except]
      incl = self.nested_attributes_options.keys.map(&:to_s) - Array(options[:except]).map(&:to_s)
    else
      incl = self.nested_attributes_options.keys
    end
    options = { :include => incl }.merge(options)
    super(options)
  end

  def to_nested_hash(options = nil)
    self.serializable_hash(options)
  end
end
```